# How do I validate that a password entered into a form is 8 characters long?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I need to ensure that a password entered into a form is at least 8 characters long. What is the best way to perform this validation in ASP.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with a [ValidationExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.validationexpression%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) like this: `.{8,}` (any character, 8 or more of that)